# WPF how to restore Button background color

Tags: wpf, button

This question felt so simple but I just can't find the answer:

How to change a Button back to its default? My VS2010 start giving me button with strange color and I have to manually set the Button to look like its default self.

I tried:

> `btn.Background = null; // only make it transparent, not default background`

Anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [ClearValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.clearvalue(v=VS.100).aspx)-method to restore the default.

```
btn.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);
```

or

```
btn.ClearValue(Control.BackgroundProperty);
```

This sets back the background-property of the button. But if you have changed the buttons template, this will not help. In this case, look for explicit declarations of the [Button.Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx)-property or for a style that sets the Button.Template-property. Look especially in your App.xaml if there is something like

```
<style TargetType="Button">
  ...
</style>
```

or

```
<style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  ...
</style>
```

Comment: How would you be able to do this in MVVM?